# Using scrapy to only follow URLs where the response.body() matches arbitrary criteria

Tags: scrapy

I am using a simple crawl spider in scrapy for Python 2.7 and Scrapy version 1.1.2. It looks something like the code below. I have a function that analyzes text (let's call it MyFunction) and returns true or false, and I would like to only follow URLs where the response.body for the URL being scraped returns true.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['example.com']

rules = ( Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('something/', ), deny=('something=', )), callback = 'parse_item', follow = True)

def parse_item(self, response):
        ru = response.url
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s',ru )
        #does some regex here to extract text and saves to a file
        item = myItemClass()
        #populates the field in my item. I don't know if I really need to do this.
        return item
```

I have looked into process_links and process_request, but they don't seem to have access to the actual response.body. I have considered actually making a new request in my process_links(example below) function, but this is running incredibly slowly and I am not sure if it is working as intended. It fetches about 1 URL per minute instead of 10+ per second.

```
def link_filtering(self,links):
    ret = []
    for link in links:
        req = urllib2.Request(link)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        the_page = response.read()
        if MyFunction(the_page): ret.append(link) # My function is some custom function that always returns true or false on a given text input
    return ret
```

Just as an example, let's pretend MyFunction checks if the substring 'asdf' is in a string. I would like to get all the URLs on my start page, and then only follow the URLs on pages that contain 'asdf' in the response.body.

Comment: Calling `urllib2.urlopen()` will do synchronous/blocking network operations and will block your thread until you get a response, which defeats the asynchronous networking idioms that make scrapy handle so many requests per minute.

Comment: Do you want to download pages and, depending on the page content, you extract links from it and follow the links? Otherwise, I'm not sure I get it: you want to follow a URL (fetching the page) depending on content you haven't fetched yet. To know the content of a URL, you need to follow it.

Comment: @paultrmbrth I would like to do the former. I want to download pages, and only follow URLS depending on page content. The goal is to focus the crawl to only follow URLS from websites of interest. Unfortunately MyFunction is something that needs to be applied to the content of a web page, not a URL.

Comment: Maybe you don't need `CrawlSpider` and you can implement the same thing with a simpler `Spider` and a link extractor in your callback, extracting link only after you checked `response.text`

Comment: You were right! Using a normal spider I was able set up my parse function so that scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse) was only called if the response.body had specific characteristics. Thanks!!!!!